# Issue with uiview, scroll not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

i'm using storyboard for present my interface, this view controller show from `mapView` through modal `segue`, but after i change orientation in view scroll is not working
[image]

[image]

**Any idea? Please, help**

Comment: what is exactly not working ?

Comment: check autolayout constraints.